# ¿Por qué este script de video se muestra en cualquier dominio?

Tags: php, javascript, redirección

Estoy haciendo un reproductor, la idea es que solo se muestre en mi dominio, lo intenté con PHP y JavaScript pero no funciona.
Esto es lo que pensé e hice:

```
<?php
$host= $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"]; 
// echo $host; 
if ($host=="midominio.com") {
    # code...

?>
<br />
<div id="player">
</div>
<script>

</script>

<?php 
}

else{
 ?>
 <script type="text/javascript">
window.location="http://www.midominio.com";
</script>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: el echo que tienes comentado te regresó **localhost** o **127.0.0.1** ?

Comment: el dominio sin el "http://www."